# Creating application level packets in Python

Tags: python, tcp, packets

I have a basic multi-threaded client server running using python 3.6

Now once a connection is established I want to create application level packets which will be sent over tcp/ip. The purpose of these will be make a three-way handshake to identify multiple clients then authenticate them. the packet will also be used to send certain payloads to the server.

Since python does not have any data type such as structures so i am having a hard time creating these packets.I cant use tuples because they are immutable, I have tried using recordclass and using Structures from c_type.

Data is not sent properly while using recordclass, because i dont know the exact size each packet will be, i kept the recv() argument to a maximum limit but this moves the client to a blocking state if the packet's length is shorter then the maxium limit. 
And in using c_type structures i can send the data but it is received in a format like this **\xbct\x00\x106\xe0\x02ff\xc8B** and I cant convert it back to the original form.

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT:
So far i have done this. I am attaching below the code snippets i am using, the structure fields are just arbitrary i will change them later on.

Server Side:

```
...
   ...
   class app_packet(Structure):
       _fields_ = [('packet_type',c_wchar_p),
                  ('sensor_name',c_wchar_p),
                  ('value',c_float)]

   syn=app_packet('syn','temperature',100.2)
   connectionSocket.sendall(syn)
   ...
   ...
```

Client side:

```
    ...
    ...
    class app_packet(Structure):
        _fields_ = [('packet_type',c_wchar_p),
                    ('sensor_name',c_wchar_p),
                    ('value',c_float)]

    data=clientSocket.recv(1024)
    syn=unpack('3s4sf',data)
    a=str(syn)
    print("unpacked="+a)
    ...
    ...
```

But the problem still remains, even after i unpack the received packet the string data remains in byte format, whereas the float data is converted properly. this is what i get for the output of the print statement

```
unpacked=  (b'(\xbcY', b'\x00\xa0\xa6\xc2', 100.19999694824219)
```

I have tried different encoding/decoding schemes but nothing is working so far, and i can not convert it back

Comment: Python _does_ have such datatypes—you found them in `ctypes`—but typically you want to use the `struct` module to de/serialize a more "normal" value into a bytestream, or to build (or download) a higher-level serialization library built on top of that. If you can give us a [mcve] I can show how to do that for your case.

Comment: Also, the data are received as a stream of bytes because that's what you sent, just as they would be in, say, C. If you want to use a `ctypes.Structure`, you need to convert the bytes back to it, the same way you had to convert the structure to bytes to send it.

Comment: One more thing: If you _do_ want to build things around Structure instead of the `struct` module, one quick hack that's often helpful, at least during development, is a class decorator that wraps a Structure in a Union with a char or uint8 array of the same byte size. That makes casting between the two representations a bit more readable—just set the bytes element and then read the attributes off the structure element or vice-versa. If that sounds like something you want and you can't figure out how to write it, it's not hard to demonstrate.

Comment: And one last thing—is there a reason you need these to be mutable? For handshake data, I can't imagine what you'd want to change after constructing (on the send side) or converting from bytes (on the recv side). A `namedtuple` with a `struct`-based method for converting to and from the wire protocol seems like exactly the right kind of thing, if you don't want to use something higher level.

Comment: @abarnert firstly thank you for your help. Could you please tell me the way to convert the bytes back? is there any predefined method it. The reason i want these is to be mutable is that I am actually trying to create one single packet that contains all the fields i need, and then according to the packet type i will set the relevant fields, if they're immutable i cant do that. And even if i do make another separate packet for the handshake, i need to send my client id in it, so that will eventually change.

Comment: @abarnert i have attached the code i am using for testing purposes, if you will kindly have a look at it.

Comment: Do you have to use a binary protocol? If you don't, then a simple solution would be newline delimited json messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you're not actually sending the strings.

You've defined a structure that includes two `c_wchar_p` members—or, in C terms, `wchar_t *` pointers. You send those pointers over, and but never send the data they're pointing to. That can't possibly work.

You can't just send C `struct`s containing pointers in any language. You have to write some higher-level protocol that includes the actual strings instead of the pointers in some way, and then write the code that serializes and deserializes to the `struct`. Which is much easier to do with functions like `struct.pack` instead of around a `ctypes.Structure`. And even easier to do on top of a higher-level protocol like [netstrings](https://cr.yp.to/proto/netstrings.txt), and even easier if you just use a text-based protocol with some human-readable framing, like newline-escaped JSON texts with newlines as delimiters.

---

If you really want a binary protocol based on just dumping fixed-sized structures to the network, your structs have to be fixed-sized and self-contained. For example, if your `packet_type` were always at most 4 characters, and your `sensor_name` at most 30 characters, and it were acceptable to waste space for shorter names, you could do this:

```
class app_packet(Structure):
    _fields_ = [('packet_type',c_wchar*4),
                ('sensor_name',c_wchar*30),
                ('value',c_float)]
```

Now the characters are embedded directly in the structure, so it will work.

---

Except that it won't really work, because your data types aren't network-portable. A `wchar_t` can be either 2 bytes or 4 bytes—not just between different platforms, but even between binaries built with different compilers or flags on the same platform. (Plus, they're of course native-endian.) If you really want embedded 2-byte or 4-byte strings, you have to be explicit about it: use `c_uint16` or `c_uint32`, encode with `s.encode('utf-16')` or `s.encode('utf-32')`, then either `memcpy` or `cast` and slice-copy. But then of course they're not strings within your code until you pull them out, cast them back, and decode them, at which point you might as well be using a proper protocol in the first place.

---

Also, it's still not clear why you'd ever want handshake data to be stored in a structure like this in the first place. Why not just pass it around as a tuple (or `namedtuple` or normal class) with two strings and a float, and serialize/deserialize right as it goes over/comes in from the network.

You mentioned in a comment that you need them to be mutable, but that doesn't explain it; it makes even less sense that you'd want mutable handshake data. And besides, you can trivially just make a new tuple with different strings instead of having string-like members that you can mutate in place.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help! I understand the mistake i made using `c_wchar_p` . i have changed my code to use tuples and used the _struct.pack/unpack_ to send it and now its working properly.